# Twitter API works only with one method

Tags: php, twitter

```
$key = 'fd2fdfsdfsdfdsf';
$secret = 'fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdf';

$basic_credentials = base64_encode($key.':'.$secret);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Authorization: Basic '.$basic_credentials."\r\n".
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        'content' => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$pre_token = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', false, $context);

$token = json_decode($pre_token, true);

if (isset($token["token_type"]) && $token["token_type"] == "bearer")
{
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token["access_token"]       
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $data = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/users.json?q=twitter', false, $context);
    var_dump($data); die();
```

The code above returns false. I have no idea why. When I change the url into:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=200&user_id=43243243
```

It works perfectly and returns the whole JSON.

Why is that so? I can't get it to work with any other API methods other than this one. The key and secret are the same in each situation. Nothing should be changed.